# How to add another program which do manipulation in imported Excel sheet using Tkinter program

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I have created two python programs. One in which I am doing all the manipulations like sorting the data in Excel file using xlrd and xlwt. Another is I created a GUI using Tkinter and importing the original Excel file on which I need to do the manipulations

My question is how to add this program for manipulation in Tkinter program so that on click I will get required file with all the manipulations done. Both the programs are working individually

Comment: You could call the other .py script via the command line, but why not combine them?

Comment: Hello, can you share the source code for your initial attempt to achieve your purpose, and show in your source code where you're having problems? This can let others help you probably easier and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `import` keyword:

1. Put both files in the same directory, name them like variables (the name does not start from a number, contain dashes etc. Example: `gui.py` and `operations.py`)
2. Put everything from the operations file (except imports) in a function. Example:

```
import random

def main():
    for x in range(10):
        print(random.randint(1,10))
```

3. Use the `import` keyword:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
import operations

tk = Tk()
Button(tk, command=operations.main).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

where `operations` (twice) is the name of your file with a function, minus the `.py` part, and `main` - the name of a functon.

There's a different way, a bad one, that's os-specific but does not require the `main` function. Depending on the OS you could try:

```
import os

os.system('python3 operations.py')# variation 1
os.system('python operations.py')# variation 2
os.system('py -3 operations.py')# variation 3
```

Hope that's helpful!